# Customize a Json object to follow a specific format

Tags: php, json, laravel

In my Laravel API, email validation error response comes like this...

```
{
    "status": 409,
    "message": {
        "emailAddress": [
            "A user with email: my@email.com already exists."
        ]
    }
}
```

The `message` value comes from this : `$validator->messages();`

Now, what I want is to get the error response like this json format

```
{
      "status": 409,
      "message": "A user with email: my@email.com already exists"
}
```

How to get this done by going inside `$validator->messages();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return the first error to your user, you can handled that by using the `MessageBag` as a `Collection`, like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->input(), [
  "email" => "...",
  "password" => "..."
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  $firstError = $validator->messages()->first();
  return response()->json(["status" => 409, "message" => $firstError], 409);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For larval 5.6 and above you can use below solution.

Edit file under app/Exceptions/Handler.php and add following files

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request) {
    if ($e->response) {
        return $e->response;
    }

    $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(["errors" => $this->error_to_json($errors)], 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput(
        $request->input()
    )->withErrors($errors);
}

protected function error_to_json($errors) {
    $json_errors = $errors;

    $new_errors = array();
    foreach ($json_errors as $key => $value) {
        $new_errors[$key] = $value[0];
    }

    return $new_errors;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|emails|exists:users',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 409, 'message' => "A user with email: ' . $request->email . ' already exists"], 200);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! But, this `$validator->fails()` becomes true for every validation fail. (eg: Password is too short), So, how to write the error message for that ?

Comment: Hard-coding the `message` is not going to work for this, unless there is only one field/rule being validated.

Comment: You can check error fields inside if statement to see which parameters cause error and provide your message for each one.